# How to intertwine two strings or arrays, possibly with String.Join()

Tags: c#, arrays, string, cartesian-product

I have the following string arrays:

```
var myArray1 = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};
var myArray2 = new string[] {"t1", "t2"};
```

I would like to be able to produce a final string that looks like this:

```
var myFinalString = "t1.A, t2.A, t1.B, t2.B, t1.C, t2.C";
```

I know I can iterate through each element of the array and build the string manually. However, I'd like to know if there's a better way. I tried to figure out how to make `String.Join()` method work, but couldn't :-(.

Comment: So you have two arrays, one being {'A', 'B', 'C'} and the other {"t1", "t2"} ?

Comment: And you want to multiply both and then make a string from the resulting array?

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed typing the 2nd array there. Will update the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
var query = from x in new[]{"A", "B", "C"}
        from y in new[]{"t1", "t2"}
        select y + "." + x;

var result = string.Join(", ", query.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know that any direct method exists, but this one-liner

```
return 
  from a in myArray 
  from b in tTerms 
  select string.Format("{0}.{1}", b, a)
```

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

The term for such sequence is ["Cartesian Product"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Here is long blog by Eric Lippert on it [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)

As it is already shown in other answers sequence of tuples can be obtained with following code and than aggregated (using Join in case of string, or Aggregate for other type of result) to produce your final string:

```
var product =
    from first in s1
    from second in s2
    select new[] { first, second };
var result String.Join(", ", 
   product.Select(p => String.Format("{0}.{1}", p.first, p.second));
```

Comment: While that's a great link and code snippet, here it seems that there will always be just 2 sets, so you don't need that more generic version; you can just use a single `SelectMany` call.

Comment: @Servy, Sure. I know that it is to generic - for useful answer there are high up-vote answers already :)

Comment: Thank you for educating me on what this is called. I'll edit the post accordingly so that others might find the answers.

Answer (score -1):

If the two sequences are of the same length, you could probably put [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) to work for you.

```
var myFinalString = myArray.Zip(mySecondArray, (f, s) => f + "." + s);
```

Comment: He needs the Cartesian product.  That's not what `Zip` does.